# How to pass image width and height inside code

Tags: php, wordpress, categories

I am using this plugin to grab images from my categories in wordpress: http://zahlan.net/blog/2012/06/categories-images/

I am having trouble passing an image size through the code. I am not amazing with PHP but can get around as needed.

I am trying to make my images 200x200 width and height. Any help on how to do this would be greatly appreciated.

I want to pass this through wordpress/php so the images is forced to keep it's proportions if possible. Thanks!

Below is my code:

```
<ul>
        <?php foreach (get_categories() as $cat) : ?>
      <li>
        <img src="<?php echo z_taxonomy_image_url($cat->term_id); ?>" />
        <a href="<?php echo get_category_link($cat->term_id); ?>"><?php echo $cat->cat_name; ?></a>
      </li>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
```

Thanks so much!

Comment: <img src="<?php echo z_taxonomy_image_url($cat->term_id); ?>"  height=200; width=200 />

Comment: Thanks for the response Orbit. I am actually looking at passing it through the string so wordpress generates the thumbnail with some proportions remaining. I probably should have mentioned that sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<img src="<?php echo z_taxonomy_image_url($cat->term_id, 'medium'); ?>" />
```

or you can use

```
<img src="<?php echo z_taxonomy_image_url($cat->term_id, array(200, 200)); ?>" />
```

or

```
<img src="<?php echo z_taxonomy_image_url($cat->term_id, 'thumbnail'); ?>" />
```

Comment: Thanks so much for this. The first one was what I wanted. Thank you for taking the time to help out!

Answer (score 1):

```
<ul>
        <?php foreach (get_categories() as $cat) : ?>
      <li>
        <img src="<?php echo z_taxonomy_image_url($cat->term_id); ?>" />
             $imgsize = getimagesize($cat); 
$imgString[] = array('url' => $cat,'width' => $imgsize[0],'height' => $imgsize[1]);
        <a href="<?php echo get_category_link($cat->term_id); ?>"><?php echo $cat->cat_name; ?></a>
      </li>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
```